# Script that will show area of rectangle

Tags: shell-script

I am looking to write a script which will prompt the user for two numbers, representing the width and height of a rectangle in centimetres, and output the area of the rectangle in both square metres and square inches (one inch = 2.54 centimetres).

I feel this should be relatively simple, but I can't come to a working conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: The chapter on [arithmetic expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) in the Advanced Bash Scriting Guide might be useful to you.

Comment: note that sh can only do integer arithmetic.  but you can use `bc` and other tools (e.g. `dc` if you want to use stack-based/reverse-polish arithmetic, e.g. `3 5 +` rather than `3 + 5`) to do floating point calculations.   e.g. `area=$(echo "$width * $length" | bc)` or `area=$(echo "$width $length * p" | dc)`

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post. It just creates work for people to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Enter the width and height of rectangle in meters: " width height 

sqm=$(echo "$width * $height" | bc -l)
sqin=$(echo "$sqm * 1550" | bc -l)

echo "Area of the rectangle is: $sqm Square Meters or $sqin Square Inches."
```

(FYI, 1 square meter is 1550 sq inches. I know this because google tells me so.)

Sample run:

```
$ ./area.sh 
Enter the width and height of rectangle in meters: 3.5 4.5
Area of the rectangle is: 15.75 Square Meters or 24412.50 Square Inches.
```

Answer (score 0):

After correcting one or two typos in the code you put in your comment above, it should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter the width and height of rectangle:"
read width 
read height 
echo "Area of the rectangle is:"
expr $width \* $height
```

Result:

```
$ ./tst.sh 
Enter the width and height of rectangle:
3
4
Area of the rectangle is: 
12
```

So, where's the problem? ;)

Comment: ... try entering `1.2` and `5` for width and height, I think you will notice a problem ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
read -r -p "please enter width of rectangle: " W
read -r -p "please enter height of rectangle: " H
AREA=`echo "$W $H" | awk '{area=$1*$2; print area}'`
echo "Area of the rectangle is:$AREA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type the following:

```
touch area.py
chmod 700 area.py
```

Paste this in area.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
W = input('Enter the width of the rectangle: ')
L = input('Enter the length of the rectangle: ')
A = float(W) * float(L)
print(f'The area is {(A)}')
```

When you run the program you will be asked to enter the length and width and the computer will return the area.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my post above.  I wasn't able to delete or edit my old post so I just posted a new one. I realized that you wanted the instructions for shell and not python. Just in case, I will put the instructions for both.

#### SHELL

Open Terminal and type the following:

```
touch area.sh&&chmod 700 area.sh
```

Paste this in `area.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Enter the width of the rectangle'
read W
echo 'Enter the length of the rectangle'
read L
echo "The area of the rectangle is $((W * L))"
```

#### Python

Open Terminal and type the following:

```
touch area.py&&chmod 700 area.py
```

Paste this in `area.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
W = input('Enter the width of the rectangle: ')
L = input('Enter the length of the rectangle: ')
print(f'The area of the rectangle is {float(W)*float(L)}')
```

Hope this helps!